# error when using @tensorflow/tfjs in angular 6 project

Tags: angular, tensorflow.js

I have generated an angular 6 project with no other dependencies the project is super clean the only dependency is the @**tensorflow/tfjs**

The message I get if I serve my project on localhost:4200 say this:

> Module not found : Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in C:\User\user\bla\bla
>   [image]

The problem is I want a feature that tensorflow supports only on the last 5 versions and whatever version I chose from 0.11.1 and above always fails to compile or fail when web pack starts to bundle the code.

this is a GitHub issue on tensorflow.js I have made but no solution yet.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/494

A live code can be found here.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eu4cjy

#### Also code example here

#### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit  {



  // TRAINING DATA.
  x_train = tf.tensor2d([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]);
  y_train = tf.tensor2d([[0], [1], [1], [0]]);

  // Defining a model.
  model: tf.Sequential;

  prediction: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  async initModel() {

    this.model = tf.sequential();
    this.model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 8, inputShape: [2], activation: 'tanh' })); // input layer
    this.model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, activation: 'sigmoid' })); // output layer
    const optimizer = tf.train.sgd(0.01);
    this.model.compile({
      optimizer: optimizer,
      loss: 'binaryCrossentropy',
    });


    // Creating dataset
    const xs = tf.tensor2d([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]);
    xs.print();
    const ys = tf.tensor2d([[0], [1], [1], [0]]);
    ys.print();
    // Train the model
    await this.model.fit(xs, ys, {
      batchSize: 1,
      epochs: 1500
    });

    const saveResults = await this.model.save('localstorage://my-model-1');

    const loadedModel = await tf.loadModel('localstorage://my-model-1');
    console.log('Prediction from loaded model:');
    // loadedModel.predict(tf.ones([1, 3])).print();



  }

  train() {
    this.initModel();
  }

  predict() {

    const xs = tf.tensor2d([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]);

    this.prediction = this.model.predict(xs);
    console.log(this.prediction);

  }

}
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-template",
  "description": "",
  "homepage": "https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eu4cjy",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.0",
    "core-js": "2.5.5",
    "rxjs": "6.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "0.12.0"
  },
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Ideally, since `@tensorflow/tfjs` package appears to ship a browser bundled version it should point the package.json field `browser` to the file. See also

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9827#issuecomment-369578814

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10681#issuecomment-396848967

Comment: This also can help you https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10681#issuecomment-389160125

Comment: thank you @yurzui base on links you have provided me I have tried to create a crypto folder inside the node_modules but again after I initialize a node module I get an error that crypto is a core module of the node and this is true in newest versions of the node the crypto is part of node.js core what should I do, can you post an example, maybe this is gona helps more. again thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> With the help of **Nick Kreeger** the solution is this. but before that i
>   hope the issue is gonna be fix on the later angular or tensorflow
>   versions.

#### Edit this file

```
`node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.js'
```

and changed the lines in that regex:

```
// old:
node: false,
// new:
node: { crypto: true, stream: true },
I found an issue that you should chime-in on to help fix this down the road: angular/angular-cli#10954
```

Hope this helps!

### I found new solution 10/4/2019

just add these lines on your **package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": { },
  "dependencies": { },
  "devDependencies": { },

  // ======================
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false
  }
  // ======================

}
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you!